# Calculate AVERAGE from 2 columns for each row in SQL

Tags: mysql, average

As an example I will have this table from MySQL

```
Id  | Name  | Grade 1  | Grade 2 | Average

1.  | Jack  | 9        | 10      |
2.  | Jimmy | 9        | 8       |
2.  | Emmy  | 9        | 7       |
```

So, in the Average field from this table, I need to calculate the AVERAGE from the **Grade 1** and **Grade 2** fields. I tried a lot of possiblities which I know they are wrong like:

```
UPDATE table_name SET Average=AVG(Grade 1 + Grade 2)
```

I there a way to do this? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: no need to do `AVG()` since its to find the average of data. Since you need to do for 2 colums and as @JohnConde suggested try as `set average = round((grade1+grade2)/2)` this should do the job. If you do not need round up then just remove round function

Comment: @JohnConde that `/ 2` is superfluous if using the `AVG` function.

Comment: `AVG()` is an aggregate function that calculates tha average across all the rows, it's not for calculating the average within a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the fields together and divide by the number of fields.  If your `Average` field is of `DECIMAL` type you don't really even need to specify the `ROUND` function. Any decimal exceeding the declaration will just be truncated ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8fe3/1)) :

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET AVERAGE = (grade1 + grade2) / 2;
```

In your example you only have two fields that you are getting the average of.  So `Average decimal(3,1)` would work for you since the most the decimal portion will ever be is `.5`.  So the `ROUND` function is clearly not needed.