# Phpmyadmin can i make the instance of a table be summed up from other instances?

Tags: database, database-design

I am new in databases and especially phpmyadmin i want to create a database for restaurants and in the table of the user_ratings i have 3 instances service music and food rating and i want some how if its possible those ratings to be summed and divided to show the restaurant overall rating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280947/calculate-average-from-2-columns-for-each-row-in-sql

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an application for managing a MySQL or MariaDB installation; you should tag this with the proper database for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- compute the average when inserting and store it in another column (either computed by your application or as part of the SQL statement),
- use a view which will act basically like a table with the extra column computed by MySQL when you display it, or
- compute the average when selecting (again, either computer by MySQL or your application).

Personally, I'd do it on display by using a MySQL statement like `` SELECT `id`, `name`, (`service`, `music`, `food`) / 2 from `user_ratings`; ``